# How to make more than query in the same axios in Node js?

Tags: mysql, node.js, reactjs, express

I want to add TeacherSSN & SectionNameID to the table (section), this is the database:
[image]

My question is what wrong in this code in the back end (Node js, MySQL, Express)?

```
app.post("/addSection", (req, res) => {
    const TeacherName = req.body.TeacherName;
    const SectionName = req.body.SectionName;

    const SSN;
    db.query(`SELECT SSN FROM user WHERE FullName = "${TeacherName}"`, (err, result) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err)
      } else {
        SSN = result;
        console.log(result)
      }})

    const ID = db.query(`SELECT ID FROM sectionname WHERE SectionName = "${SectionName}"`);
    
    console.log(SSN);
    console.log(ID);

    db.query(`INSERT INTO section(TeacherSSN, SectionNameID) VALUES (?,?)`,
      [SSN, ID],
      (err, result) => {
        if (err) {
          console.log(err);
        } else {
          res.send("Values Inserted");
        }
      }  
  )
    })
```

How can i get the SSN and ID? To add them to the section table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several remarks about your code:

1. The assignment `SSN = result` happens *asynchronously*, after the first database query is completed, but you want to use the value of `SSN` in the INSERT statement, which is executed *synchronously*. In other words: The first query is sent, then the second query is sent, then the INSERT statement is sent, all synchronously. Only later do the responses for the two queries come in, asynchronously. That's when the `(err, result) => ...` functions are executed. So `SSN` receives its value *after* it has been used.
2. `result` does not contain the SSN value directly. According to the [`mysql` documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql#introduction), you must write `SSN = result[0].SSN;`
3. Your second query `const ID = db.query(...)` uses a different form, without the `(err, result) => ...` callback function. In this form, it returns a promise, not the section ID that you expect.
4. You create the SQL queries through string operations, which exposes your database to the risk of [SQL injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-injection). Use placeholders (`?`) instead.
5. How is the database field `sectionname.ID` filled during the insert operation?
6. Can you be sure that the `FullName` and `SectionName` are unique in their database tables?

Assuming they are unique and the `sectionname.ID` is generated by the database automatically, you can perform the insertion with a single SQL statement:

```js
db.query(`INSERT INTO section(TeacherSSN, SectionNameID)
          SELECT user.SSN as TeacherSSN, sectionname.ID as SectionNameID
            FROM user, sectionname
           WHERE user.FullName = ? 
             AND section.SectionName = ?`,
         [req.body.TeacherName, req.body.SectionName],
         (err, result) => ...);
```

This obviates the need to wait for the result of a query before you make an insertion.